# User with Full Control access to a site collection is not able to add users to group (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: javascript, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, access, access-denied

I am a Site collection admin and I am able to add users to groups via Rest API. But another user who isn't an admin, but has 'Full Control' access tries, he gets this "Access denied" message.

```
value: "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
```

Is this a limitation? That only site collection admins can add users to a group?

**My end use case is to:**

1. Let a user with Full Control access create a list
2. Break permission inheritance of that list
3. Create a new user group
4. Add a new set of users to this group
5. Allow this group to access the list

Full control users get the "Access Denied" error on No.5 in the above list.

Any way to achieve this either with REST or a 2010 workflow?

Comment: Who is the owner of newly created group? User should be owner of group to add new members to the group.

Comment: This is what the rest request looks like when the user creates the group:

{__metadata: {"type": "SP.Group"},
                "Title": "${groupName}",
                "Description": "${groupDescription}"
            }

Would that make him the owner automatically, since he created the group?

Comment: yes, user should be the owner of group.